# Problem with bringing up a custom linux board based on Firefly rockchip px30-jd4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, boot

I am new to embedded linux and I am trying to bring up a custom board based on this board [Firefly px30 board](https://en.t-firefly.com/product/coreboard/core_px30_jd4). Although I have succeeded in building an OS for the Firefly development board using this tutorial [build firmware buildroot](https://wiki.t-firefly.com/en/Core-PX30-JD4/buildroot_compile.html), when I tried the same one with the custom board, which have some differences in the eMMC and RAM used, the boot can go pass the SPL, Uboot and go to kernel boot, but then it stuck their waiting for udev to populate and then it stucked there for a couple minutes and process some more  to enter the console but then it just enter some kind of recovery mode and hanged forever. The log of the whole thing can be seen in here

```html
[    4.561530] hrtimer: interrupt took 3316042 ns
[    4.861930] rkisp1 ff4a0000.rkisp1: clear unready subdev num: 1
[    5.125404] rockchip-mipi-dphy-rx: No link between dphy and sensor
[    5.130597] rockchip-mipi-dphy-rx: No link between dphy and sensor
[    5.134412] rkisp1: update sensor failed
[    5.235411] ALSA device list:
[    5.237457]   #0: rockchip,rk809-codec
[    5.425933] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2018.02-rc3-ga31246734b-dirty
ID=buildroot
VERSION_ID=2018.02-rc3
PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2018.02-rc3"
Starting logging: OK
Populating /dev using udev: [   32.594985] udevd[160]: starting version 3.2.7
[   35.656630] udevd[160]: specified group 'kvm' unknown
[   41.338788] udevd[161]: starting eudev-3.2.7
udevadm settle failed
done
Initializing random number generator... done.
Starting network: cmdline=storagemedia=emmc androidboot.storagemedia=emmc androidboot.mode=normal  androidboot.slot_suffix= androidboot.serialno=17c5e6b3cec0121  ro rootwait earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xff160000 swiotlb=1 console=ttyFIQ0 root=PARTLABEL=rootfs rootfstype=ext4 overlayroot=device:dev=PARTLABEL=userdata,fstype=ext4,mkfs=1 coherent_pool=1m systemd.gpt_auto=0 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1

read console from cmdline is /dev/ttyFIQ0
Starting recovery on Fri Aug  4 14:49:54 2017

Recovery System have UI defined.
failed to read font: res=-1, fall back to the compiled-in font
[  340.555547] Freeing drm_logo memory: 1236K
rotate degree: 0 - none, 1 - right, 2 - down, 3 - left.
current rotate degree is : 0
OK
Debug: configfs_init
mkdir: can't create directory '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/rockchip/functions/uac1.gs0': No such file or directory
mkdir: can't create directory '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/rockchip/functions/uac2.gs0': No such file or directory
[  596.411078] file system registered
mkdir: can't create directory '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/rockchip/functions/mtp.gs0': No such file or directory
mkdir: can't create directory '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/rockchip/functions/rndis.gs0': No such file or directory
[  607.061489] Mass Storage Function, version: 2009/09/11
[  607.064402] LUN: removable file: (no medium)
mkdir: can't create directory '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/rockchip/functions/hid.usb0': No such file or directory
[  632.533934] read descriptors
[  632.552351] read strings
[  637.673944] dwc2 ff300000.usb: bound driver configfs-gadget
[  637.884795] dwc2 ff300000.usb: new device is high-speed
[  637.991626] dwc2 ff300000.usb: new device is high-speed
[  638.060663] dwc2 ff300000.usb: new address 31
[  638.102361] configfs-gadget gadget: high-speed config #1: b
[  638.347754] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
[  638.433970] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
Starting input-event-daemon: input-event-daemon: Start parsing /etc/input-event-daemon.conf...
input-event-daemon: Adding device: /dev/input/event0...
input-event-daemon: Adding device: /dev/input/event1...
input-event-daemon: Start listening on 2 devices...
done
[root@buildroot:/]# recovery filesystem table
=========================
  0 (null) /tmp ramdisk (null) (null) (null)
  1 /dev/root / ext2 rw,noauto 0 1
  2 proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
  3 devpts /dev/pts devpts defaults,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
  4 tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs mode=0777 0 0
  5 tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=1777 0 0
  6 tmpfs /run tmpfs mode=0755,nosuid,nodev 0 0
  7 sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
  8 debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs defaults 0 0
  9 pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore defaults 0 0
  10 /dev/block/by-name/misc /misc emmc defaults 0 0
  11 /dev/block/by-name/oem /oem ext2 defaults 0 2
  12 /dev/block/by-name/userdata /userdata ext4 defaults 0 2

emmc_point is /dev/mmcblk2
sd_point is (null)
sd_point_2 is (null)
Recovery start....................
read cmdline
>>> Boot from non-SDcard
[I/]RECOVERY devices is not MTD.
[I/]RECOVERY Boot command: boot-recovery
[I/]RECOVERY Got arguments from boot message
[I/]RECOVERY devices is not MTD.
Command: "recovery" "--wipe_all"

Formatting /userdata...
format '/dev/block/by-name/userdata' to ext4 filesystem
executing '/sbin/mke2fs'
[ 1122.173088] udevd[161]: worker [308] /devices/platform/ff390000.dwmmc/mmc_host/mmc2/mmc2:0001/block/mmcblk2/mmcblk2p9 is taking a long time
executed '/sbin/mke2fs' done
executed '/sbin/mke2fs' return 0
executing '/sbin/e2fsck'
e2fsck 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/block/by-name/userdata: 11/416976 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 49888/1665083 blocks
executed '/sbin/e2fsck' done
executed '/sbin/e2fsck' return 0
[ 1160.243298] EXT4-fs (mmcblk2p9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Data wipe done.
userdata wipe done.
executing '/sbin/e2fsck'
e2fsck 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
Superblock last write time (Wed Apr  6 07:50:30 2022,
    now = Fri Aug  4 15:03:48 2017) is in the future.
Fix? yes

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/block/by-name/oem: 18/4368 files (5.6% non-contiguous), 12657/17408 blocks
executed '/sbin/e2fsck' done
executed '/sbin/e2fsck' return 0
executing '/sbin/resize2fs'
resize2fs 1.43.9 (8-Feb-2018)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/block/by-name/oem to 65536 (1k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/block/by-name/oem is now 65536 (1k) blocks long.

executed '/sbin/resize2fs' done
executed '/sbin/resize2fs' return 0
resize oem done.
finish_recovery Enter.....
[E/]RECOVERY Can't open /tmp/recovery.log
[E/]RECOVERY Can't open /tmp/recovery.log
[I/]RECOVERY devices is not MTD.
Rebooting...
Reboot...
[ 1195.659147] cpu cpu0: min=816000, max=816000
```

The SDK firefly given is not really based on buildroot because the kernel, Uboot and loader are build manually with makefile and buildroot is only used to generate a root file system.

I guess that is because of different hardware need different configuration. So I have tried to turn off some peripherals in the the device tree to make a minimal OS which just able to finish boot up but it just did not work. Then I found on github [Rockchip Yocto](https://github.com/JeffyCN/meta-rockchip) and I follow through the tutorial to build a image as well as binary file but because the project was designed to run on a [Rockchip development board](https://www.graperain.com/ARM-Embedded-PX30-Development-Board/) I have to use the some filesystem file from the build with the original kernel, loader, uboot and modified the partition file from Firefly to process the boot as in this issue [link](https://github.com/JeffyCN/meta-rockchip/issues/15), but it is not working also. I tried to ask the guy from Rockchip but they only give me a vague answer that my eMMC is not fast enough to partion [link](https://bbs.t-firefly.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3133&extra=page%3D1) but I had checked and the speed is not that huge of a difference and I also tried to boot from SD card but the problem is still the same so I do not know what to do with the error right now.

So the question is that is there any thing that i missed or any one having the same problem can show me a way out. Thank you very much for any kind of help.

Comment: Looks like you can load and execute a SPL, U-Boot, and kernel, but have issues with a rootfs mounted from eMMC.  The simplest scheme for a rootfs would be an initramfs using Busybox for the init system.  This can easily be built using Buildroot (i.e. both a custom Linux kernel and the initramfs built as a single image file).  If you can get that working, then add utilities to checkout the functionality of your custom HW.  Then work on a rootfs on eMMC.  IOW proceed in small steps, instead of trying to leap from nothing to use everything at once.

Comment: Thank you @sawdust. I am happy to recieve your advice. But the only thing that i do not get in you answer is that if building a custom kernel and initram using buildroot as one img to check the functionality of my custom HW is needed, how can I do it with the Firefly SDK? Since I have tried to change some kernel setting in menuconfig in buildroot provided by the board vendor but nothing really change because they build the kernel manually using make. So my question is that how can i cope with this type of senerios. Does I need to change the files in kernel directory and build manually?

Comment: You will need to learn how to use the flexibility of Buildroot.  Instead of a tarball of a mainline-version of the Linux kernel, you can specify a URL or a local copy.  Same for the kernel configuration: instead of a standard defconfig, you can specify your own defconfig or **.config** file.  Similar choices for the Device Tree.  Whatever kernel modifications you have can be handled by Buildroot.  You just have to use its **menuconfig** to change the default settings to instead use your customized files/choices.

Comment: thank you @sawdust for your answer I now know what I have to do. Thank you for being very helpfull